# Why is Amazon Lens on by default?

Tags: lenses, shopping-lens

Why by default? And how do we get Canonical to listen to it's users/customers?
I wanted to start programming and contributing to Ubuntu on the user friendly side of things but I just can't get past this.

Comment: This was (and is) actually an answerable question: it is possible to explain, with citations (such as [to Mark Shuttleworth's blog](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1182)) why dash searches include Amazon by default. I disagree strongly with that design decision, as do many people, but we still know *why* it happened. The question here was narrowly scoped and objectively answerable, and still is.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the Amazon shopping Scope as well as other shopping scopes in Unity, open **Terminal**, then copy & paste the command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

This answer comes from [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/how-to-disable-amazon-shopping.html) **How To Disable Amazon / Shopping Suggestions And Other Unity Scopes In Ubuntu 13.10**

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's on by default is that no one would use it otherwise.

It isn't adware (they aren't ads), they're only providing search results relevant to what the user asked for. Same as with the other multiple scopes that come preinstalled. By providing an opt-out, Canonical allows users who don't want the results to remove them from their results, while ensuring that people who like/don't mind the results to get the most utility out of the box.

Comment: Luckily a simple `sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-lens-*` fixes this all.